# ExtJS 4 how to create and display a new controller/view from another controller/view?

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs

I have looked over lots of examples of ExtJS 4 MVC, and they all pretty much show the same thing:  The application creates a viewport, loads in a view, and has a 'controllers' defined, which init's the controller:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'AM',

    controllers: [
        'Users'
    ],

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'userlist'
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

Thats great, but now let's say in my application I want a button contained within my view to open a whole new controller/view, how do you do that?

I think what I am looking for is a way to say something like:
 - Create Controller (run it's init code)
   - in the controller init code, create the view and display it

Is that correct, and how do you do this?

I want to clarify that in my case I would need TWO individual instances of the SAME controller/view combination.   For example, I might have a view with a tab panel and two tabs.   I then want to put TWO separate instances of a 'Users' controller and 'user.List' view inside each tab.

Answer (score 8):

> I think what I am looking for is a way to say something like: - Create Controller (run it's init code) - in the controller init code, create the view and display it

In extjs, all controllers get instantiated when the application is loaded. You can use the launch method in the `Application` class to start off a view. And Have a controller listen to events of that view. In a controller, you can always access the other controller using the `application` object:

```
 this.application.getController('ControllerName1').displayListPanel(options);
```

In the above code, I am calling a method `displayListPanel` that is available in ControllerName1 controller. This method holds the code to display a view (a grid panel) onto the screen. Similarly, I can have methods that create views like a new form for data entry. Here is another example:

```
this.application.getController('ControllerName1').newDateForm();
```

and In my method:

```
newDataForm : function() {

        var view = Ext.widget('form',{title: 'New Data'});
        view.show();
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

Just checked the documentation of new controller and view classes.

It seems to me, that you could always find needed view when you need it.
For example you can:

```
//somewhere in controller
this.getView('Viewport').create(); // or .show()
```

check this and view class methods:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-getView